# PHP preg_replace bug?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using the following regex's:

```
$sEmailHTML = preg_replace ("/<\!-- +(\\[[\"a-zA-Z_]+\\]) +-->/U", "\\1", $sEmailHTML);
$sEmailHTML = preg_replace ("/\\[\"(.+)\"\\]/U", "\\1", $sEmailHTML);
```

on this text:

```
["Text:"]
<!-- ["Click this to authenticate"] --> <!-- [authlink] -->
<!-- ["Dear"] --> <!-- [firstname] --><!-- [":"] -->
```

and it's giving me this result: (having also replaced [authlink] and [firstname])

```
Text:
<!-- Click this to authenticate --> <a href="http://www.mydomain.tld/auth.php?jj=100&aa=SOMEVALUE&end">http://www.mydomain.tld/auth.php?jj=100&aa=SOMEVALUE&end</a>
Dear John<!-- : -->
```

when it should be giving this:

```
Text:
Click this to authenticate <a href="http://www.mydomain.tld/auth.php?jj=100&aa=SOMEVALUE&end">http://www.mydomain.tld/auth.php?jj=100&aa=SOMEVALUE&end</a>
Dear John:
```

I can't figure out why it's not removing all of the HTML comment tags.
It also doesn't work if I execute the comment remover regex twice.
So it's either a bug or I'm missing something. (PHP 5.2.17)

**THANKS. I wasn't thinking. Changed to and working:**

```
$sEmailHTML = preg_replace ("/<!-- +(\\[[a-zA-Z_]+\\]) +-->/U", "\\1", $sEmailHTML);
$sEmailHTML = preg_replace ("/<!-- +(\\[\".+\"\\]) +-->/U", "\\1", $sEmailHTML);
$sEmailHTML = preg_replace ("/\\[\"(.+)\"\\]/U", "\\1", $sEmailHTML);
```

Comment: Why is the `!` escaped? Why are there two square brackets `[[` at the beginning of the comment text block?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the text

```
"Click this to authenticate"
```

has spaces in them and your regex:

```
"/<\!-- +(\\[[\"a-zA-Z_]+\\]) +-->/U"
```

does not match spaces. Also, to match a literal `[`, use `\[`, not `\\[`.

Change it to:

```
"/<!-- +(\[[\"a-zA-Z_ ]+\]) +-->/U"
                     ^
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/MLj8J)